# Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Tags: pdo, php

Есть код:

```
$news_get = $db->query("SELECT * from `news` ORDER BY  `id` DESC");
$main_tpl_value = 'news.tpl';
$news_all = "";
while($news_get = $news_get->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

$one_post = '<p>'.$news_get['title'].'</p>
            <p>Опубликовано: '.$news_get['posted'].' Автор: '.$news_get['author'].'</p>
            <p>'.$news_get['text'].'</p>';

$news_all = "$news_all $one_post";

}
```

Который выбивает мне следующую ошибку:

```
Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in Z:\home\test1.ru\www\private\main.php on line 9
```

Строка 9 это:

```
while($news_get = $news_get->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

т.е., как я понял, он не может преобразовать данные в асс.массив, что ли. Переписывал и под prepared-запрос - итог тот же.

Помогите разобраться, в  чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @Etki, преобразуйте свой коммент в ответ, чтобы я мог его как правильный отметить)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> т.е., как я понял, он не может преобразовать данные в асс.массив, что ли.

не ленимся перевести

> вызов метода fetch() у переменной, не являющейся объектом

далее просто анализируем код и понимаем, что `$news_get` перетирается на каждом цикле, а значит, уже на втором проходе while метод вызвать нельзя.